# How to insert multiple value data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my select option I have value with two numbers Example **value="163, 162"**

I have a model function where can insert the first value number which would be **category id 163**

Var Dump

`array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "163" [1]=> string(4) " 162" }`

**Question:** I need to add `parent_id = " . $this->db->escape($category['parent_id']) . "` but not sure how to get the second value number and set it as the `parent_id = " .  $this->db->escape($category['parent_id']) . "` **parent id would be example 162**

**Model Function**

```
public function page_update($page_id, $data) {
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "page_to_category WHERE page_id = '" . (int)$page_id . "'");

    if (isset($data['categories'])) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as $category) {

            //$data_sample = explode(',', $category['category_id']);
            //var_dump($data_sample);
            //exit;

            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "page_to_category SET 
            page_id = '" . (int)$page_id . "', 
            category_id = " .  $this->db->escape($category['category_id']) . "
            ");
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="categories[1][category_id]">
            <option value="0">-- No Category Required --</option>
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) {?>
            <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>, <?php echo $category['parent_id'];?>" selected="selected">
            <?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>, <?php echo $category['parent_id'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
            <?php }?>
            <?php }?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats your actual problem can you please elaborate? What you want to do with comma separated values?

Comment: When I use explode I can not get the second number `value="163, 162" ` I need to be able to get the second number

Comment: Why you not using CI `insert` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be something like this:

```
public function page_update($page_id, $data) {
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "page_to_category WHERE page_id = '" . (int)$page_id . "'");

    if (isset($data['categories'])) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as $category) {

            $data_sample = array_map("trim",explode(',', $category['category_id']));
//Here $data_sample[0] will always be your category id and $data_sample[1] will be your parent id


            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "page_to_category SET 
            page_id = '" . (int)$page_id . "', 
            category_id = " .  $this->db->escape($data_sample[0]) . "
            ");
        }
    }
}
```

Here $data_sample[0] will always be your category id and $data_sample[1] will be your parent id

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy and preferable to use Codeigniter syntax, in case you might want to have a look, this code does the same as @Arcanix answered but uses CI Active Record syntax,

```
public function page_update($page_id, $data)
{
    $this->db->delete('page_to_category', array('page_id' => (int)$page_id)); 

    if (isset($data['categories']))
    {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as $category)
        {
            $data_sample = array_map("trim",explode(',', $category['category_id']));

            $insert_data = array(
                            'page_id' => (int)$page_id,
                            'category_id' => $this->db->escape($data_sample[0])
                        );

            $this->db->insert('page_to_category', $insert_data); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do multiple inserts, You can do it with active records. First create an `array` of datas which you want to insert, and then use `insert_batch` method

```
$insertdata = array(
   array(
      'email' => 'email' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'email' => 'some data' ,
      'name' => 'some data' ,
      'date' => 'some data '
   )
);
$this->db->insert('mytable', $insertdata);
```

You can get more info from here [Insert methods used in CodeIgniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)